# Jquery Masking UI issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I actually need to show SSN into my UI with formatted text. so i was wondering can we apply jquery mask method on it. because i have only heard that we can apply masking on Input type. So please reply me. it would be great help to me.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: As per my knowledge, masking of very important fields like SSN should be done at either the database level or the service level and should not be done at the UI level as the data can be misused/tampered.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for your concern. actually my SSN is coming from database layer and i am getting it to UI through JSON. the thing is, it is just not formatted. i need to format it on the UI side.